# RaphaelJS will not build with typescript

Tags: typescript, raphael

I am trying to include an existing raphaelJS figure into some new code, but keep getting an error.

> Cannot call a namespace ('Raphael')

I've installed both **@types/raphael** and **raphael** into devDependencies. using the below line to import it into the typescript file.

```
import * as Raphael from 'raphael';
```

I have a feeling the error has something to do with the createPaper() function, but different combinations of Raphael and raphael don't give better results

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createPaper(this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
    this.drawCompass(this.radius, this.thickness);
    this.drawDirection(this.radius, this.thickness);
}

private createPaper(width: number, height: number) {
    this.paper = Raphael(this.compass.nativeElement, width, height);
    this.paper.setViewBox(0, 0, width, height, true);
    this.paper.canvas.setAttribute('width', '100%');
    this.paper.canvas.setAttribute('height', '100%');
  }
```

Comment: "I've installed both @types/raphael and raphael into devDependencies." -- Are you getting the namespace errors during runtime?  Are you missing `raphael` as a dependency?  Did you mean to install `@types/raphael` into devDependencies and `raphael` as a dependency?

Comment: It was decided that we would rewrite the code to expand upon a different module, the maths needed to draw the shapes will be reused, but not `raphael`. @nwayve I misspoke and had `raphael` as a dependency like you mention, not devDependencies as i wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration for `raphael` uses an [export assignment](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/raphael/index.d.ts#L298), so the module should be imported using an import assignment:

```
import Raphael = require("raphael");
```

Or if you have the `esModuleInterop` option enabled, you can use a default import:

```
import Raphael from "raphael";
```

When `esModuleInterop` is enabled, a namespace import like `import * as Raphael from "raphael";` loses the callability of the original export assignment.  (When `esModuleInterop` is disabled, a namespace import keeps the callability, but this is considered legacy behavior.)

I tried your code with TypeScript 3.1.3 and got a better error message and offers of code fixes for both of the above alternatives (I didn't research the TypeScript version in which this functionality was introduced), so it's good to stay up to date.

Comment: Thank you for trying, it was decided to go with a different approach, but I'll remember you're suggestions for future module trouble.